# Multiple corresponding authors in BioMed Central LaTex template

Tags: titles, templates

I am using the BioMed Central LaTex template in order to submit a scientific paper that has the formatting required for such journal.

The only problem I am finding is that I do not seem to be able to indicate more than one author as a corresponding author. There is a .cls file included along with the .tex template where I think the problem would be, but authors are discouraged to modify that .cls file.

The BioMed Central template can be found at http://www.biomedcentral.com/authors/tex [bmc_article (ZIP format) link]

If you give it a try, you can go to the following lines in the .tex file:

```
\author[
   addressref={aff1},                   % id's of addresses, e.g. {aff1,aff2}
   corref={aff1},                       % id of corresponding address, if any
   noteref={n1},                        % id's of article notes, if any
   email={jane.e.doe@cambridge.co.uk}   % email address
]{\inits{JE}\fnm{Jane E} \snm{Doe}}
\author[
   addressref={aff1,aff2},
   email={john.RS.Smith@cambridge.co.uk}
]{\inits{JRS}\fnm{John RS} \snm{Smith}}
```

it works for just one corresponding author, but if I want to make both authors corresponding authors and add:

```
   corref={aff1,aff2},
```

for John RS Smith too, it will no longer interpret Jane E Doe as a corresponding author ('??' instead of '*' and no contact information under '*Correspondence').

Check the following images, the first one is the template as is, with only Jane E Doe as corresponding author.

[image]

This second picture correspond to the template when I try to make both authors corresponding authors... It only understands John RS Smith and adds a '??' for Jane E Doe, omitting her contact information under '*Correspondence'.

[image]

Any clue anyone?? Any help would be really appreciated. It's crucial that I get this done asap, preferably without modifying the accompanying .cls file. Many many many thanks!

Comment: I got this answer from them:
Thank you for contacting BioMed Central.

The BioMed Central template is based on our submission system.

Since our system can only list one contact author, this is also the case for the template we provide.

If you have any questions please do not hesitate to contact me.

Best wishes

Comment: Articles have one corresponding author. That's why it's called corresponding author. In case you need correspondence, you contact the corresponding author. In Word, anything is possible, in a shrewed way, that's why they usually take the first author in case there are multiple marks.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because as detailed in comments this is really a policy decision by the publisher.